# strange error with drawing

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2, quartz-graphics

```
"_GContextSetFillColorWithColor", referenced from:
  -[GraphView drawLineGraphWithContext:] in GraphView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What does this  error mean? It seems to happen at this line?

```
GContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.5 blue:0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you spelt it wrong. You should have had a warning from the compiler.

Comment: yeap that's it. Warning wasn't very clear: implicit declaration of function is invalid in C99'